# Forms.form or Forms.Model

Tags: django, forms

I have read all the supporting documents for forms in Django, and all the answers provided on stackflow - I am still not sure what one I want to use.

I am creating a Model that will produce a "Specials" page on a website.

The specials page will have:

```
*Title
*Image
*Discription
* Form (get this special)
```

From the admin area the site admin can ad as many specials as they want - but each special created must have this exact same format just one under the next. I followed the (Poll) tutorial to create as much of model as possible - actually it did most of it for me.

The docs and stackflow did a good enough job of explaining ImageField so that works - kinda.

But this form has got me all twisted up - can some one please give me an idea of which Form instance I want to use -

Note: I do not want the form to show in the ADMIN section, just display on output.

Any help would be great
Thanks